# Docker compose, can't talk to exposed port when run individually?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I ran two services individually

```
docker-compose run --service-ports django /bin/bash
docker-compose run --service-ports other /bin/bash
```

Although I can see the ports in `docker ps`, a service can't talk to the exposed ports in another service.

$ docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES

586e859afcab        littlehome_other                 "/bin/bash"              12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       6379-6380/tcp, 9200/tcp    zibann-reservation_other_run_6

994dadb0ad7f        littlehome                       "/bin/bash"              25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       0.0.0.0:10011->10011/tcp   zibann-reservation_django_run_3
```

docker-compose.yml has

```
 services:
  django:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: littlehome
    depends_on:
      - other
      - nginx
    env_file:
      - ./compose/.envs/production/postgres
    # command: /app/compose/production/django/uwsgi.sh
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:10011:10011"

 other:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/other/Dockerfile
    image: littlehome_other
    # depends_on:
    #   - postgres
    expose:
      - "9200"
      - "6379"
      - "6380"
    volumes:
      - ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history
```

I'm tyring to let `django` talk to `other:9200`

`docker network inspect zibann-reservation_default` shows

```
  "Containers": {
        "994dadb0ad7f59e6a9ecaddfffe46aba98209ff2ae9eb0542f89dee969a85a17": {
            "Name": "zibann-reservation_django_run_3",
            "EndpointID": "02bf3e21aba290b999d26f0e52f2cb6b3aa792a10c86e08065d0b299995480dd",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:06",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.6/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "ac5b1845f31f23bce0668ee7a427dc21aafbda0494cf67cc764df7b0898f5d23": {
            "Name": "zibann-reservation_other_run_7",
            "EndpointID": "b6cfcbfbf637d6521575c300d74fb483b47d6fa9e173aeb17f9c5bfc12341a37",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "fe83a3addb7365b2439870e887a4eae50477f1c3531c6af60a91a07bb1226922": {
            "Name": "zibann-reservation_postgres_1",
            "EndpointID": "bee7d0fcc80f94303306d849fbb29a3362d1d71ceb7d34773cd82ab08bc80172",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
```

The service is elasticsearch and client is trying to connect to elasticsearch via `'http://other:9200/reviewmeta_index/_count'`  Would this work ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they are connected to same network.

Check you network with **docker network ls** (use value from here to connect later)

Check which bridge your containers are using: **docker network inspect bridge**

And connect the right network: **docker network connect default-bridge zibann-reservation_django_run_3** (default-bridge being your the network you want to connect. Can be anything of course)

More detailed information can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-the-default-bridge-network and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/#related-commands

Comment: When i run `docker inspect $(container_id)` for the two services, it shows the same Network.  `            "Networks": {
                "zibann-reservation_default": {` . Doesn't this mean they are connected to the same network? (I haven't read the tutorials yet)

Comment: I've updated the op with the docker network inspect , it seems that both services are connected to the same network (zibann-reservaton_default)

Comment: You can manually check if connection is there by connecting the django server "docker exec -it 994dadb0ad7f bash". (telnet the port, or install lynx etc.) The ip-addresses seem to change from time to time after restart, so also make sure you are making the connection to right ip address.

Comment: found out the elasticsearch configuration file needed to change to allow other hosts to connect (something like host='*')

Comment: Wonderfully useful debugging knowledge even if the problem/solution for me was different.